# Media key problems with Microsoft keyboard

Tags: xorg, keyboard, systemd, keyboard-layout

I have a Microsoft All-in-One wireless media keyboard (n9z-00001) which behaves weirdly with my current distribution, Arch Linux. (`Linux 3.19.3-3-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Apr 8 14:10:00 CEST 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux`)

```
$ lsusb | grep -i micro
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 045e:0800 Microsoft Corp.
```

And this is what xinput yields. Note that there are two keyboards for this device, one with the peculiar `(keys)`

```
$  xinput list | grep -i micro
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0    id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0    id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0 (keys) id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0    id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I can listen to the keys directly with `evtest`. Although it is the same keyboard

```
$ sudo evtest
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:  Lid Switch
/dev/input/event1:  Power Button
/dev/input/event2:  Video Bus
/dev/input/event3:  Video Bus
/dev/input/event4:  AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
/dev/input/event5:  Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0
/dev/input/event6:  Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0
/dev/input/event7:  Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0
/dev/input/event8:  ThinkPad Extra Buttons
/dev/input/event9:  HDA Digital PCBeep
/dev/input/event10: HDA Intel PCH Mic
/dev/input/event11: HDA Intel PCH Headphone
/dev/input/event12: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/dev/input/event13: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7
/dev/input/event14: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8
/dev/input/event15: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
/dev/input/event16: Integrated Camera
/dev/input/event17: Logitech M705
/dev/input/event18: TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint
/dev/input/event19: daskeyboard
/dev/input/event20: daskeyboard
Select the device event number [0-20]:
```

- The device id 9 from `xinput` corresponds to `/dev/input/event5`, which has all the regular keys except some of the media keys.
- id 10 corresponds to `/dev/input/event7`, and has the media keys on `F1-F4` and 6 other keys related to volume control and other microsoft stuff.
- I am guessing that `/dev/input/event6` corresponds to the touchpad on the keyboard.

The problem is with the function keys. Media keys that are placed where `F1-F5` should be are assigned to the "`(keys)`" device, whereas `F6-F12` are assigned with the other one. **I want to map the media keys back to the function keys so that I don't have to press Fn every time.**

**Problem 1:** Media keys (keys that are channeled through input device 10, the `(keys)` one) are not registered by `xev`. They generate output with `showkey --scancodes` and `evtest`, but they are not picked up by X. How to solve that?

**Problem 2:** 
Media keys that work through input device `9` send multiple scancodes, and AFAIK there is no way of remapping multiple keys with `hwdb`, as shown in [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Map_scancodes_to_keycodes). The following are the scancodes sent by the media key on `F7`

```
Event: time 1430059493.552417, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
Event: time 1430059493.560416, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e0
Event: time 1430059493.560416, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL), value 0
Event: time 1430059493.560416, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e3
Event: time 1430059493.560416, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 125 (KEY_LEFTMETA), value 0
Event: time 1430059493.560416, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
```

I have no idea how to bind multiple scan codes to a single event; right now X is detecting all the individual keys and maps them to the respective events. For example, according to the output above, media key on `F7` sends `Ctrl+Alt+Scanner`. How can I do this, since googling left me with no results?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue? B.t.w. we've solved the related touch pad problem here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227264/is-it-possible-to-tweak-input-from-touchpad

Answer (score 1):

Instead of remapping the keys, you can press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>CapsLock</kbd> which locks the F buttons to F buttons instead of multimedia and vice-versa if you press it again.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works with newer firmware versions of the keyboard. It got implemented in the firmware after much negative feedback (Check the ratings in online shops). But there is no patch to fix old ones. Mine is from 2014/09 and doesn't have this functionality yet. I don't know when they added it.

Comment: That is really awful, if my one didn't have this switch I wouldn't have bought it. I'm having other issues with the touchpad, it is not identified as a touchpad so I cannot disable tap click, the keyboard is nice, but those are big issues.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem finally after i uninstall xf86-input-joystick package problem solved
https://forum.manjaro.org/t/microsof-all-in-one-keyboard-problem/15560

Comment: It would be great if you could write the essentials of your link into your answer.

Comment: I am sorry i couldn't understand well but the answer has already written before link