# Is it possible to tweak input from touchpad?

Tags: x11, touchpad, scrolling, xinput

I use a MS [keyboard](https://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/all-in-one-media-keyboard) on my Debian machine. The problem is that MS does not ship configuration software for us and touchpad's default scrolling directions are reversed (it uses natural scrolling).

I wonder if it's possible to tweak the input from the particular input device somehow so it behaves "normally". I.e. I would like to replace `scroll-up` and `scroll-down` commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a kind pointing by @Gilles to `xinput` I was able to swap scroll directions by using the `set-button-map` command.

First you should lookup the device id or name using the `list` command and then remap scroll wheel buttons like this `xinput set-button-map id 1 2 3 5 4 7 6`.

Published a small [script](https://github.com/Kolyunya/media-keyboard-scroll-fix) which does this automatically.

Answer (score 3):

You can control some settings of input devices with [`xinput`](http://www.x.org/archive/current/doc/man/man1/xinput.1.xhtml). Run `xinput list` to list devices. Each device has a name and a numerical ID. You can use either this name or this ID to list properties of the corresponding device. Device IDs can depend on the order in which the devices are detected, so to target a specific device, use its name. For example, I have a mouse as device 8; here's an excerpt of its properties:

```
$ xinput list-props 8
…
    Evdev Axis Inversion (272):     0, 0
    Evdev Axes Swap (274):  0
…
```

Either of the following commands makes my cursor go right when I move my mouse left, and up when I move it down:

```
xinput set-prop 8 272 1 1
xinput set-prop 8 'Evdev Axis Inversion' 1 1
```

If you want to swap the direction of wheel emulation, there are properties for that: change `Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes` from `6 7 4 5` to `7 6 5 4`.

Comment: Thank for pointing to the `xinput`, that was very helpful. But the `Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes` is not the option I was looking for. This option only works with the emulated wheel (i.e. if when I emulate the wheel with the middle click). Haven't figured out how to invert native scroll wheel yet.

Comment: @Kolyunya So what do you want to tweak: the wheel feature, or normal cursor movement?

Comment: I would like to tweak only scroll wheel direction, not the cursor movement. The `Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes` does not work with the physical wheel, only with the emulated one. Maybe it's possible to use the `--set-button-map` to swap `Button Wheel Up` and `Button Wheel Down`?

Answer (score 0):

Remapping an individual device with xinput and .xsessionrc

I had a similar issue where I wanted to reverse scrolling on one device.
The ID didn't work for me because it changed with each start up. Using the device name did work.

Type the following line in terminal to find the name of the device:

```
    xinput list
```

Then use a text editor to edit or write .xsessionrc in the home directory. Example:

```
    vim ~/.xsessionrc
```

Note: I recommend typing "sudo vim ~/.xsessionrc" to simplify issues with write permissions if the file already exists, as was in the initial example before review.

Then add the following line to `.xsessionrc` with "name" replace by "device name from `xinput list`". Keep the quotes.

```
    xinput set-button-map "name" 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

For example, I wanted to reverse vertical scrolling (4 5) and horizontal scrolling (6 7) on my "Microsoft Wedge Touch Mouse".
`xinput list` gave me:

```
    ⎜   ↳ Microsoft Wedge Touch Mouse               id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

So I added the following line to `.xsessionrc`

```
    xinput set-button-map "Microsoft Wedge Touch Mouse" 1 2 3 5 4 7 6
```

Finally, log out and in.

This worked on Mint Cinnamon 17.3